# Use Shell script to retrieve max number of users' activity in a file

Tags: shell

Given a /var/log/messages file as below that recording different users sending Emails records, for example:

```
20140912 chris sendingemails_id00012jjdi3x
20140912 chris sendingemails_id00012jjdiji
20140912 alen sendingemails_id00012jwciscl
20140914 chris sendingemails_id00012jjdiji
20140915 linda sendingemails_id042555jwciscl
20140915 chris sendingemails_id00012jjdiji
20140916 alen sendingemails_id005hhbxxsscl
20140917 chris sendingemails_id2221d2rwaaiji
20140917 linda sendingemails_id00012baseeqcl
20140918 chris sendingemails_id45677tehhwaaiji
```

Now, I need to retrieve the user who sends emails the most. How can I do it? 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help:

```
cat /var/log/messages | grep "sendingemails_" | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c
```

OR to get exactly the username:

```
cat /var/log/messaes | grep "sendingemails_" | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -r | head -1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't know to use uniq to do the job.